# Custom Block Magento 2 isnt't working

Tags: php, module, magento2

i wanted to add a new function to `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View`

what i did:

**1.** `app/code/Company/Module`

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "Company/Module",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "100.0.2",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Cms\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

**registration.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Company_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

**2.** `app/code/Company/Module/Product/View`

Inside this file:

```
 <?php

namespace Company\Module\Block\Product;

class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View {

    private function trySomething()
    {

        exit('test');return '123';
    }
}


?>
```

**3.**  `app/code/Company/Module/etc`

Inside this folder:

```
di.xml
```

Content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" type="Company\Module\Block\Product\View" />
</config>
```

Also in the folder:

```
module.xml
```

Content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">

    </module>
</config>
```

I am tying to call the function over a template, included into product_detail like this:

```
/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @var $block \Company\Module\Block\Product\View
 */

?>
<?php echo  $block->trySomething(); ?>

This is just another test
```

The Text "This is just another test" is shown correctly on product_detail but the function won't be called.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself, the problem was that block and layout wasn't in the same module. I created a `view/frontend/layout` and `view/frontend/templates` under `app/code/local/Company/Module` this solved it 4 me.